# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((100, 28, 28, 10) vs (100, 10))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, anomaly-detection

I am attempting to do an anomaly detection NN with the MNIST fashion dataset as my input.

Currently, my model is as such

```
from keras.models import Model

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)) 

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.summary()
```

The summary is the following

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_44 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPoolin  (None, 14, 14, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_45 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_19 (MaxPoolin  (None, 7, 7, 32)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_46 (Conv2D)          (None, 7, 7, 32)          9248      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_20 (MaxPoolin  (None, 4, 4, 32)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_47 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 4, 32)          9248      
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d_18 (UpSamplin  (None, 8, 8, 32)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_48 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 8, 32)          9248      
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d_19 (UpSamplin  (None, 16, 16, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_49 (Conv2D)          (None, 14, 14, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 up_sampling2d_20 (UpSamplin  (None, 28, 28, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_50 (Conv2D)          (None, 28, 28, 1)         289       
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 46,849
Trainable params: 46,849
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1932, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5247, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((100, 28, 28, 10) vs (100, 10)).
```

May I know how this error is produced, like where, and how may I fix it. The code is based on an article i found, but as it was incomplete, along with my inexperience in this type of Neural Network, I do not know how to fix it.

Here is how I transformed the data

```
data=tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = data
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.utils import to_categorical
X_train = X_train / 255
X_test = X_test / 255
# one hot encode outputs
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Here is how I am trying to train the model (where the error occurs)

```
history=autoencoder.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), 
          epochs=10, verbose=2, batch_size=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be working with an `Autoencoder`, try:

```
data=tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = data
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')


history=autoencoder.fit(x=X_train, y=X_train, validation_data=(X_test,X_test), 
          epochs=10, verbose=2, batch_size=100)
```